# Why does my webview finish unexpectedly?

Tags: android, webview, keyevent

I place a fragment with a webview widget to load my webpages and create a host fragmentActivity as my webpages' container. Now that there is a page, including a media player, seems like to support various of content for us. Here comes the problem, if I click the play button, the media player works well itself, however, when i adjust the power of  volume, either higher or lower, the host activity finish unexpectedly. Complementally, I just handle the back event in the method of onKeyEvent.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      if(webview.canGoBack()){
         webview.goBack();
         return true;
     }
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Anybody helps me?

Comment: @Denny  Not crash scene. I don't want to finish the webview, when I adjust the volume of my phone. Can I modify this default action?

Comment: if you override "onBackPressed" instead of "onKeyDown" happen same issue?